# AppInit_DLLs and LoadAppInit_DLLs not working on Windows 11 despite disabling secure boot and setting the correct path to DLL file

Tags: c++, windows, dll, windows-11, dll-injection

I have created a simple DLL check:

```
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {
    MessageBox(0, 0, 0, 0);

    return true;
}
```

This is the registry:

[image: Screenshot of my regedit]

I have tried everything, but my DLL injection is not working.

Expected behavior: When opening an app, it should show a blank error message

Actual behavior: Nothing happens.

Comment: Why disable secure boot?

Comment: Because of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/secure-boot-and-appinit-dlls).

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows 7, DLLs loaded by `AppInit_DLLs` need to be code-signed by default, unless you set `RequireSignedAppInit_DLLs` to 0. There is no `RequireSignedAppInit_DLLs` value in your screenshot.

Per [AppInit_DLLs in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/win7appqual/appinit-dlls-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2):

> AppInit_DLLs is a mechanism that allows an arbitrary list of DLLs to be loaded into each user mode process on the system. **Microsoft is modifying the AppInit DLLs facility in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 to add a new code-signing requirement.** This will help improve the system reliability and performance, as well as improve visibility into the origin of software.
>
> ...
>
> Windows 7
>
> **All DLLs that are loaded by the AppInit_DLLs infrastructure should be code-signed.** In the interests of application compatibility, the Windows 7 Operating System will load all AppInit DLLs. **However, Microsoft recommends that all application developers code-sign their DLLs to help improve the reliability of Windows and prepare for code-signing enforcement in future versions of Windows**. The `RequireSignedAppInit_DLLs` registry key controls this behavior and its value on Windows 7 is set to 0 by default.
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> **All DLLs that are loaded by the AppInit_DLLs infrastructure must be code-signed.** The `RequireSignedAppInit_DLLs` registry key controls this behavior and its value on Windows Server 2008 R2 is set to 1 by default.

---

Also, note that `MessageBox()` is in `user32.dll`, and [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices) clearly states:

> You should never perform the following tasks from within `DllMain`:
>
> - ...
> - Call functions in User32.dll or Gdi32.dll. Some functions load another DLL, which may not be initialized.
> - ...

You should use [`OutputDebugString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw) instead, and then use a tool like [SysInternals DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to see the messages.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I tried adding RequireSignedAppInit_DLLs and setting it to 0. After reboot my DLL still is not loaded.

Comment: Hi! Did you happen to resolve? How did you do it? Thanks!